# WATIN is there a more effective way to programe this

Tags: watin

I want to get all LI with class type equals itempep

This is how I do it now, but its very CPU intensive task

ElementCollection eL = frame.Elements.Filter(Find.By("tagname", "LI") && Find.ByClass("itempep_hp"));

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need `ElementCollection`? This could be faster:

```
frame.ElementsWithTag("LI").Where(e => e.ClassName == "itempep_hp");
```

Comment: frame.ElementsWithTag("LI")

Thanks, lots of faster with the method above